# Suggest mp3 player having minimum requirements

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3-player

Please suggest an mp3 player which does the following things apart from play, pause, next & previous. I'm not looking for all the equalizer & stuff. Just playing & option to enqueue at one click is good for me.

1. Enqueue on double click/Enter or enqueue on right click on the file (like in Windows for Winamp & Foobar).
2. **Doesn't** save the previous playlist
3. Hotkey or laptop key support (Optional)
4. Simple GUI

Please don't suggest Amarok & Exaile as it's buggy with 10.04.
Currently I'm using DeadbeeF, which I liked, but looking for enqueue option as I'm tired of drag & drop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Enqueue option looks like the main requirement here, may I suggest that with the help of nautilus-actions, we can have an option like "Add to Playlist".

In case you are interested in the steps to do that, here they are :
1. Please install nautilus-actions if you don't have it already.

```
   $ sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

2. Open Menu -> Preferences -> Nautilus-Actions Configuration.
3. Click on the "+" icon on the toolbar to add a new entry.
4. We can name the "Context label" something like "Add to Playlist". Similarly please enter anything of your choice in the Tooltip box. We can also choose an icon for the item (need to mention the path of icon).
5. Click on the Command tab and enter your favorite music player's path like "/usr/bin/audacious" in the box.
6. For the Parameters box, I have entered "%U" (without the quotes) and working directory is "%d" (without the quotes)
7. Save.
8. Now in Nautilus go to the music directory and select multiple files and click right button and select "Add to Playlist".

This should result in the music player to run and play the selected files. It worked for me in Audacious.

Although this might not be the answer you was looking for, I thought to share my thoughts so that in case you like it you can please give it a try.

EDIT 1 : I am attaching here two screenshots of the nautilus-actions configuration tools. These are the two tabs where I have added the details. I am on Natty. I have nautilus-actions nautilus-scripts-manager and also options like nautilus-gksu installed.

Screenshot 1 : 
[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation dude. I tried the way u mentioned. I did everything except I didn't find the working directory to add "%d". I cannot see "Add to Playlist" when I right click on any song file.

Comment: I have now added two screenshots to my answer above. Also added the tools that I have installed. Hope it now works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots @Arindom. But in Lucid Lynx, it's not the case. First of all there are not many tabs. Also, in Command tab, there is no field like 'Working directory'. Rest I did the same way u explained. Thanks you.

Comment: @Rahul: Oh because I am on Natty may be my UI is different. In that case, you may want to take a look at these pages : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1612254 and http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/howto-add-items-to-the-right-click-menu-in-nautilus/ . Hopefully it works.

Comment: @ Arindom - I followed the link, & now I've found that a new option "Enqueue in DeaDBeeF" is added to my right click menu. But when I select a song to enqueue, it's playing the song file directly instead of enqueue. And I' not able to leave using DeaDBeeF as my mp3 player. Any help dude, which does this task easily? Thanks.

Comment: I am not using DeaDBeeF, so I will suggest may be you can try the different parameters, under the command section (nautilus actions) that are available. Initially in audacious also, for me, some of the parameters were working differently. So I tried some of them before suggesting you with the above steps. If still it doesn't work then I will of no further help, because my knowledge is limited. Also, if possible, can you please give audacious a try? Just to check whether the feature is working for you in audacious or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to recommend either Rhythmbox which I find very easy to use and I just use it to play mp3 using the same ideas as you..ie want it **simple** and easy to use.

It gives you the option to turn all the other 'stuff' like last.fm wiki amazon etc off permanently and just get on with your music and was very easy for me to configure when installing Ubuntu 
When installed select edit-plugins and untick all the things you do not need or indeed tick all the ones you do!

More info available here

[info re rhythmbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox)

Comment: Thanks @andybleaden for ur reply. I'm just looking for "Enqueue/Add to Playlist" button. Or like the way we add in Amarok by "double Clicking" the file. Nothing much. I'm not looking for any other things.

Comment: Thought I would have  a look here..in my desktop Ubuntu now as I am typing this (admittedly using Banshee on the pc I am on!) I just double clicked and it added it to the system queue and it started playing immediately! Did know it did that. I know that also in my preferred applications on here at the moment it is set to play mp3 auto with banshee. I then installed rhythmbox, reset the preferred app for mp3 to rhythmbox and that did exactly the same ..

Comment: .However what I notice it does not do is queue another one afterwards as  it plays that one straightaway. It also stores them under system queue too not play queue

Answer (score 0):

You should use DeadBeef's `--queue` option to enqueue files.
For example, if you'd like to add this as a **Custom Action** to **Thunar** file manager, it would be something like this:

[image]