# Is there any mp3 player which has "Add to Playlist" Option?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, mp3-player

I'm trying to find an mp3 player which has "Add to Playlist/Enqueue" option for Ubuntu/Xubuntu. I'm looking for something similar to Winamp or Foobar.
Thank you.

Note: Please don't suggest Foobnix, as it doesn't have "Add to Playlist" option.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer seems currently to be [banshee](http://banshee.fm/) as it is the default player.
It has "Add to Play Queue" and "Play After" in the right-click menu and you can use drag-n-drop for the play queue and playlists as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Clementine? You can find it in the Software Center :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a repetition of the following question in *askubuntu.com*.
[Suggest mp3 player having minimum requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43405/suggest-mp3-player-having-minimum-requirements). The question has well answered and it meets your requirement and some more as well. So follow it.

If by chance those answers are not satisfying, you can try installing `python-nautilus` package. It is a good python-plugin for nautilus and Rhythmbox that does both adding the file to the library (which is required for enqueue to work) and then enqueues the file.

For more information: http://seemanta.net/myblog/?p=509

Hope these help you :)